# Install acrobat reader using snap in 18.04 successful but not launching

Tags: 18.04, wine, snap, adobe-acrobat

Installing acrobat reader using [this link](https://snapcraft.io/install/acrordrdc/ubuntu) was successful for me now when I try to run it I get this.

```
martin@martin:~$ snap run acrordrdc
Gtk-Message: 01:41:08.336: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 01:41:08.337: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 01:41:14.107: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 01:41:14.108: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ERROR: /tmp/AcroRdrDC1801120063_en_US.exe
/tmp/AcroRdrDC1801120063_en_US.exe
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [PE] archive


wine: cannot find '/tmp/dl/setup.exe'
Failed to Fopen file /etc/wgetrc
Failed to Fopen file /etc/wgetrc
wget: Cannot read /etc/wgetrc (Permission denied).
--2020-06-07 01:41:14--  https://gist.github.com/mmtrt/896cf131e3956b23e8e47a5a52f58b01/raw/097cbd0eeb836d69a84423aaef9a7ead2840a111/acrordr
Resolving gist.github.com (gist.github.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘gist.github.com’
mv: cannot stat '/home/martin/snap/acrordrdc/common/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/AcroCEF/RdrCEF.exe': No such file or directory
wine: cannot find '/home/martin/snap/acrordrdc/common/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/AcroRd32.exe'
martin@martin:~$
```

Should I reinstall the acrobat reader using WINE and Remove this one or I can just go on and install using WINE? Will there be any conflict or broken package if I do?
I'm just tired of fixing broken packages been doing it the whole week. So I want to confirm before going on installing stuffs.

EDIT:

can successfully open gist:

[image: gist]

Comment: You have to ask developer of this great snap - https://snapcraft.io/acrordrdc on https://github.com/mmtrt/acrordrdc . Or simply install any Acrobat from PlayOnLinux.

Comment: You real problem seems to be nonstable network connectivity. Can you open https://gist.github.com/mmtrt/896cf131e3956b23e8e47a5a52f58b01/raw/097cbd0eeb836d69a84423aaef9a7ead2840a111/acrordr from web-browser?

Comment: @N0rbert yes I can open the gist properly this is its first line `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`

Comment: I'm asking because I do not have any issues installing this snap. The resulting interface of Acrobat is far from being good, but it launches normally.

Comment: @N0rbert i was thinking about this `/tmp/AcroRdrDC1801120063_en_US.exe` maybe i should i download this one? im just hesitating to download it because im afraid it would break the currently installed one.

Comment: Starting from scratch would be better - `snap remove --purge acrordrdc` , `snap install acrordrdc`.

Comment: i will try to remove and reinstall this and be back here asap